# How to create dynamic views in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to create dynamic views in asp.net mvc 2.0?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "dynamic views". What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

A better way to think about this is to have a generic view page that renders some HTML that administrator defines and which gets stored in a database.  Another alternative would be to create static HTML files -- assuming the content is fixed or could be retrieved via AJAX -- and have a view which dynamically chooses which of these HTML files to from your generic view.  I use this latter method to make certain parts of a link aggregator site I've put together maintainable by others.  It renders HTML fragments (stored in `content/static/*.htm`) onto fixed parts of the index page/view using jQuery `load`.  The admins have access to modify these files to rearrange/add/delete the links contained on that part of the page.  The app is at an early stage of development and eventually these will migrate either into configuration files, and I will generate the HTML, or perhaps I'll develop an administrative interface to manage them and keep them in the DB.